# MassTransit Custom Inbox Storage

Tags: c#, events, masstransit

I'm trying to implement MassTransit as an internal event transport for my app. I know that this is probably not the best use case for it, but I want to use some of the features that come out of the box with it like batching or retries. Also it would be nice to have one library to handle both internal and external events.

One thing I want to have is a custom persisted inbox using MongoDb to store the incoming events (for better observability and redundancy). I was able to implement a middleware, namely a scoped filter for `ConsumeContext<T>` and this gives me most of the functionality I need combined with delayed redelivery as a retry mechanism (normal retries don't go through the middleware for each retry). I was able to inject a repository to the filter and get the retry count from context there, but the one thing I am missing is the information about whether the message will be retried (redelivered) further or not.

This information is necessary for me to mark messages as `dead`, so that the background worker that is publishing the messages to consumers will not process them any further - theoretical scenario here is that let's say the consumer has `RetryLimit = 3`, but the app went down after the second retry. After it goes back up, I want the inbox worker to pick it up and try publishing it again. However if it reached 3 retries, I want to mark it as `dead` and handle it manually (I'll have some metrics and alerts for that).

The flow of events would be: domain/app event -> inbox -> inbox worker -> publish -> consumer

I know there's an option to connect an `IRetryObserver`, however I wasn't able to get a scoped repository injected to it, as that would require the observer itself to be scoped.